# DRYing up my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a code snippet which make an API call, which is currently used in 3 different view files (all belonging to different controllers).

My code:

```
<%  url_raw = URI.parse("url-tem_id=#{rec.id}") %>
<%  url = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_raw).body %>
<%  if url.empty? %>
    <%  @title          = "Product Unavailable via API" %>
    <%  @url            = "url" %>
    <%  @cover_img      = "180X180.jpg" %>
    <%  @price          = "Product Unavailable via API" %>
<% else %>
<%  begin %>
<%  @response1  = JSON.parse(url) %>
<%  @title          = @response1["ProductName"]%>
<%  @url            = "{@response1["ProductUrl"]}"%>
<%  @cover_img      = @response1["ImagePath"].gsub("75X75.gif", "500X500.jpg")%>
<%  @price          = @response1["currentItemPrice"]%>
<%  rescue %>
<%  end %>
<%  end %>
```

Im really confused about if this should be moved to a partial, helper, or application controller? Also, once this is moved, how do I call it in my view and pass in the `rec.id` variable?

Comment: This code absolutely should **not** be in any view. This is business logic; it belongs at the controller level *(in a module or action method on a controller)*.

Comment: @Deefour's comment should be the answer.  There is no view-related code in this file since it's just setting up instance variables, which *then* should be used in view files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should all be model logic... it all seems to relate to setting up attributes of a model.

I assume the "rec" is a model of some description, in which case:

```
# all psuedo-code... written off the top of my head and cut/pasting your example... ie: untested!
class Rec < AR::Base
  attr_reader :title, :url, :cover_img, :price

  def call_api!
    url_raw = URI.parse("url-tem_id=#{self.id}")
    url = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_raw).body
    if url.empty?
      @title          = "Product Unavailable via API"
      @url            = "url" 
      @cover_img      = "180X180.jpg" 
      @price          = "Product Unavailable via API" 
    else 
      begin 
        response = JSON.parse(url)
        @title          = response["ProductName"]
        @url            = response["ProductUrl"]
        @cover_img      = response["ImagePath"].gsub("75X75.gif", "500X500.jpg")
        @price          = response["currentItemPrice"]
      rescue 
    end 

  end
end
```

Then in your controller you can call "rec.call_uri!", and the views can access "rec.price", etc (personally, I'd do it slightly differently, but this shows a first-stage refactor of the code you have).

If you need it in multiple models, extract it to a module and include it.

Answer (score -1):

This is controller logic and should be moved into a module which can then be shared by the controllers.

You can create a new instance variable that is accessible to your view.

`@rec_id = rec.id`

Comment: Not a clue. Why should this be moved to a module, instead of the application controller?

Comment: You can also move it to the applications controller if you plan on using it throughout your entire app. However, if you only planning on using it in a few select places, a module would be a better choice.

Comment: I wouldn't go setting up instance variables for temporary access to attributes of other variables that are in memory; that just seems a waste of time, and will get confusing.